# Tic Tac Toe - 2 boards with fragments

Tags: java, android

I have in this problem:

In the game I need two boards where one is the copy of the other. Then you click on one of the boards and the "X" or "O" symbol is inserted based on the `player1Turn` variable.

Each board belongs to one player so the first one to the "X" and the second to "O". Both boards must have the same state during the game, so they must be synchronized.

So far I managed to make the board and I have no idea how to add another one, and use fragments as well.

1.How can I make two boards that are a copy of the other with fragments?

-My app work only for the first chessboard-

Like this

[image]

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {


     private Button[][] buttonsX = new Button[3][3];
     private Button[][] buttonsO = new Button[3][3];
     private boolean player1Turn = true;

     private int roundCount;

     private int player1Points;
     private int player2Points;

     private TextView textViewPlayer1;
     private TextView textViewPlayer2;

     @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    textViewPlayer1 = findViewById(R.id.text_view_p1);
    textViewPlayer2 = findViewById(R.id.text_view_p2);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            String buttonID = "button_X" + i + j;
            int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(buttonID, "id", getPackageName());
            buttonsX[i][j] = findViewById(resID);
            buttonsX[i][j].setOnClickListener(this);
        }
    }

    Button buttonReset = findViewById(R.id.button_reset);
    buttonReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            resetGame();
        }
    });
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    if (!((Button) v).getText().toString().equals("")) {
        return;
    }

    if (player1Turn) {
        ((Button) v).setText("X");
    } else {
        ((Button) v).setText("O");
    }

    roundCount++;

    if (checkForWin()) {
        if (player1Turn) {
            player1Wins();
        } else {
            player2Wins();
        }
    } else if (roundCount == 9) {
        draw();
    } else {
        player1Turn = !player1Turn;
    }

    }

    private boolean checkForWin() {
    String[][] field = new String[3][3];

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            field[i][j] = buttonsX[i][j].getText().toString();
        }
     }

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (field[i][0].equals(field[i][1])
                && field[i][0].equals(field[i][2])
                && !field[i][0].equals("")) {
            return true;
        }
     }

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (field[0][i].equals(field[1][i])
                && field[0][i].equals(field[2][i])
                && !field[0][i].equals("")) {
            return true;
         }
     }

    if (field[0][0].equals(field[1][1])
            && field[0][0].equals(field[2][2])
            && !field[0][0].equals("")) {
        return true;
     }

    if (field[0][2].equals(field[1][1])
            && field[0][2].equals(field[2][0])
            && !field[0][2].equals("")) {
        return true;
     }

    return false;
     }

    private void player1Wins() {
    player1Points++;
    Toast.makeText(this, "Player 1 wins!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    updatePointsText();
     resetBoard();
     }

    private void player2Wins() {
    player2Points++;
    Toast.makeText(this, "Player 2 wins!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    updatePointsText();
     resetBoard();
     }

    private void draw() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Draw!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    resetBoard();
     }

    private void updatePointsText() {
    textViewPlayer1.setText("Player 1: " + player1Points);
    textViewPlayer2.setText("Player 2: " + player2Points);
     }

    private void resetBoard() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            buttonsX[i][j].setText("");
        }
     }

    roundCount = 0;
    player1Turn = true;
    }

    private void resetGame() {
    player1Points = 0;
    player2Points = 0;
    updatePointsText();
    resetBoard();
    }
```

This is the *content_main.xml* file.

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view_p1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:freezesText="true"
    android:text="Player 1: 0"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view_p2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/text_view_p1"
    android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
    android:freezesText="true"
    android:text="Player 2: 0"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/text_view_p1" />

   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view_p8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="DOPPIOTRIX"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/button_reset"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.633"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

   <Button
    android:id="@+id/button_reset"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="reset"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
   <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="418dp"
    android:layout_height="586dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="49dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/relativeLayout"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/text_view_p1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text='GIOCATORE "X"' />

    <androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabellaX"
        android:layout_width="394dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="60dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_X22"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:freezesText="true"
            android:text=""
            app:layout_column="2"
            app:layout_row="2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_X00"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:freezesText="true"
            android:text=""
            app:layout_column="0"
            app:layout_row="0" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_X01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:freezesText="true"
            android:text="" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_X12"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:freezesText="true"
            android:text=""
            app:layout_column="2"
            app:layout_row="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_X02"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:freezesText="true"
            android:text=""
            app:layout_column="2"
            app:layout_row="0" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_X20"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:freezesText="true"
            android:text=""
            app:layout_column="0"
            app:layout_row="2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_X21"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:freezesText="true"
            android:text="" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_X10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:freezesText="true"
            android:text=""
            app:layout_column="0"
            app:layout_row="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_X11"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:freezesText="true"
            android:text=""
            app:layout_column="1"
            app:layout_row="1" />
    </androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout>


   </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="353dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text='GIOCATORE "O"' />

    <androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/TabellaO"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="60dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button22"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            app:layout_column="2"
            app:layout_row="2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_O00"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            app:layout_column="0"
            app:layout_row="0" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button02"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button12"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            app:layout_column="2"
            app:layout_row="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button.."
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            app:layout_column="2"
            app:layout_row="0" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button20"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            app:layout_column="0"
            app:layout_row="2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button."
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            app:layout_column="0"
            app:layout_row="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button11"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            app:layout_column="1"
            app:layout_row="1" />
    </androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hint: If you can narrow down your problem that would be helpful.

Comment: Edited with first point to do

Answer (score 0):

Maybe one solution could looks as follow.

**Notice that it isn't perfect and has a lot of duplicated code and much more issues, so is up to you to make it better. However it works, but if something works doesn't mean it can be marked as a good piece of code.**

First create one new fragment:

```
<Right-click-on-project> -> New -> Fragment -> Fragment(Blank)
```

and call it `BoardFragment`.

Next in the generated *layout/fragment_board.xml* put the following snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabellaX"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="10dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">



    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:freezesText="true"
        android:text=""
        app:layout_column="0"
        app:layout_row="0" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:freezesText="true"
        android:text=""
        app:layout_column="1"
        app:layout_row="0" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:freezesText="true"
        android:text=""
        app:layout_column="2"
        app:layout_row="0" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:freezesText="true"
        android:text=""
        app:layout_column="0"
        app:layout_row="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:freezesText="true"
        android:text=""
        app:layout_column="1"
        app:layout_row="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:freezesText="true"
        android:text=""
        app:layout_column="2"
        app:layout_row="1" />



    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:freezesText="true"
        android:text=""
        app:layout_column="0"
        app:layout_row="2" />


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:freezesText="true"
        android:text=""
        app:layout_column="1"
        app:layout_row="2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:freezesText="true"
        android:text=""
        app:layout_column="2"
        app:layout_row="2" />

</androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout>
```

The `BoardFragment.java` should look as below:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;


public class BoardFragment extends Fragment {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_board, container, false);
    }

}
```

Then change the activity_main.xml with the following code snippet, remeber to change the package in the `fragment` tags.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_p8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="DOPPIOTRIX"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_p1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:freezesText="true"
            android:text="Player 1: "
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_p1_score"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:freezesText="true"
            android:text="0"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_p2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:freezesText="true"
            android:text="Player 2: "
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_p2_score"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:freezesText="true"
            android:text="0"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_reset"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="reset"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:visibility="visible" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text='GIOCATORE "X"'
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <!-- Change  andorid:name-->
    <fragment
        android:name="hr.hello.dm.test.BoardFragment"
        android:id="@+id/grid_X"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text='GIOCATORE "O"' />

    <!-- Change  andorid:name-->
    <fragment
        android:name="hr.hello.dm.test.BoardFragment"
        android:id="@+id/grid_O"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Finally the Java file.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {



    private boolean player1Turn = true;

    private int roundCount;

    private int player1Points;
    private int player2Points;

    private TextView textViewPlayer1Score;
    private TextView textViewPlayer2Score;
    private GridLayout gridLayoutX;
    private GridLayout gridLayoutO;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        textViewPlayer1Score = findViewById(R.id.text_view_p1_score);
        textViewPlayer2Score = findViewById(R.id.text_view_p2_score);

        gridLayoutX = findViewById(R.id.grid_X);

        int id = 0;
        for(View v : gridLayoutX.getTouchables()){
            v.setId(id++);
            v.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        gridLayoutO = findViewById(R.id.grid_O);
        for(View v : gridLayoutO.getTouchables()){
            v.setId(id++);
            v.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        Button buttonReset = findViewById(R.id.button_reset);
        buttonReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                resetGame();
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (!((Button) v).getText().toString().equals("")) {
            return;
        }

        GridLayout currentGridLayout = player1Turn ? gridLayoutX : gridLayoutO;


        if (player1Turn && currentGridLayout.findViewById(v.getId()) != null) {
            ((Button) v).setText("X");
            ((Button) gridLayoutO.getTouchables().get(v.getId())).setText("X");
        } else if (!player1Turn  && currentGridLayout.findViewById(v.getId()) != null){
            ((Button) v).setText("O");
            ((Button) gridLayoutX.getTouchables().get(v.getId() - 9)).setText("O");
        } else {
            return;
        }

        roundCount++;

        if (checkForWin()) {
            if (player1Turn) {
                player1Wins();
            } else {
                player2Wins();
            }
        } else if (roundCount == 9) {
            draw();
        } else {
            player1Turn = !player1Turn;
        }

    }

    private boolean checkForWin() {
        String[][] field = new String[3][3];

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                field[i/3][i%3] = ((Button) gridLayoutX.getTouchables().get(i)).getText().toString();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            if (field[i][0].equals(field[i][1])
                    && field[i][0].equals(field[i][2])
                    && !field[i][0].equals("")) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            if (field[0][i].equals(field[1][i])
                    && field[0][i].equals(field[2][i])
                    && !field[0][i].equals("")) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        if (field[0][0].equals(field[1][1])
                && field[0][0].equals(field[2][2])
                && !field[0][0].equals("")) {
            return true;
        }

        if (field[0][2].equals(field[1][1])
                && field[0][2].equals(field[2][0])
                && !field[0][2].equals("")) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    private void player1Wins() {
        player1Points++;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Player 1 wins!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        updatePointsText();
        resetBoard();
    }

    private void player2Wins() {
        player2Points++;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Player 2 wins!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        updatePointsText();
        resetBoard();
    }

    private void draw() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Draw!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        resetBoard();
    }

    private void updatePointsText() {
        textViewPlayer1Score.setText(String.valueOf(player1Points));
        textViewPlayer2Score.setText(String.valueOf(player2Points));
    }

    private void resetBoard() {
        for(View v : gridLayoutX.getTouchables()){
            ((Button) v).setText("");
        }

        for(View v : gridLayoutO.getTouchables()){
            ((Button) v).setText("");
        }

        roundCount = 0;
        player1Turn = true;
    }

    private void resetGame() {
        player1Points = 0;
        player2Points = 0;
        updatePointsText();
        resetBoard();
    }
}
```

> A quick explanation:
>
> On GIOCATOREX board the X player inputs the
>   values and vice versa for the GIOCATOREO. However they can't input a
>   value when is other user turn.

Comment: But in the exercise he says to use 2 fragments of the same type